# AWS api gateway will not allow custom domain name association to certificate

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

AWS API gateway refuses to allow me to associate a custom domain to a certificate. However, it allowed me to associated the certificate just fine to another domain. The certificate is a wildcard cert. A picture is worth a thousand words:
[image]

Comment: Can you please check the endpoint configuration you want is edge-optimized or regional?

Comment: As Naveen eluded to, you can't use Custom Domain Names with Private Endpoints.  However, the error message would usually tell you that, so I can only assume you aren't using Private endpoints.  Could you provide more information on how you have configured your API Gateway please?

Comment: I want edge optimized, not regional. The endpoints have not been setup yet, it's just configuring the domain name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On April 2019, There is some enhancement for CloudFront about the security for adding alternate domain names to a distribution.

It seems that the self-signed certificate is not allowed after the enhancement.

[Amazon CloudFront enhances the security for adding alternate domain names to a distribution](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2019/04/amazon-cloudfront-enhances-the-security-for-adding-alternate-domain-names-to-a-distribution/?nc1=h_ls)

> The certificate must be valid and come from a publicly trusted Certificate Authority like AWS Certificate Manager which provides public SSL/TLS certificates for free.

Comment: My certificate was not self signed (it was signed by a trusted authority) and the first domain I added under that cert was well after 8 Apr 2019.

Comment: Maybe you can try a workaround method. First, create a Custom Domain Name by a certificate created by ACM instead of the imported one, and secondly, edit the Custom Domain Name and change the certificate to your origin imported certificate.

Comment: So, actually, it works with regional, which is fine for what I need it for because this is just a test. But I can't enable it for cloudfront.

Comment: What does it mean about "I can't enable it for CloudFront"?
Does it mean that you can't integrate regional API Gateway Custom Domain Name to self-created CloudFront?

Comment: No, it means the I can't create an edge optimized domain, just a regional domain.